# When marshalling JAXB to XML file

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb

I have an issue with the marshalling on my JAXB and don't quite understand why.
When I marshall out the data and add it to the xml file, all is correct except it imports the XML coding at the top.

Example of before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FlightDetails xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Shows">
    <FlightDetailsCollection>
        <DestinationCity>France</DestinationCity>
        <ExtraInfo>Free Wifi</ExtraInfo>
        <Date>2009-03-09</Date>
        <Fare>
            <CurrencyName>GBP</CurrencyName>
            <CurrencyFare>60.0</CurrencyFare>
        </Fare>
    </FlightDetailsCollection>
</FlightDetails>
```

Then when I add the marshalled data it appears as so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FlightDetails xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Shows">
    <FlightDetailsCollection>
        <OriginCity>London</OriginCity>
        <DestinationCity>France</DestinationCity>
        <AirlineBrand>Ryan Air</AirlineBrand>
        <ExtraInfo>Free Wifi</ExtraInfo>
        <Date>2009-03-09</Date>
        <Fare>
            <CurrencyName>GBP</CurrencyName>
            <CurrencyFare>60.0</CurrencyFare>
        </Fare>
    </FlightDetailsCollection>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FlightDetails xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Shows">
    <FlightDetailsCollection>
        <OriginCity>Germany</OriginCity>
        <DestinationCity>France</DestinationCity>
        <AirlineBrand>Virgin Air</AirlineBrand>
        <Date>2009-03-09</Date>
        <Fare>
            <CurrencyName>GBP</CurrencyName>
            <CurrencyFare>200.0</CurrencyFare>
        </Fare>
    </FlightDetailsCollection>
</FlightDetails>
```

As you can see it's added the following before putting it into the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FlightDetails xmlns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/Shows">
```

How would I be able to stop it from including the encoding and schema name? In debug it seems to be only containing the needed information so I cant trace it. I presume it was JAXB adding it in, however could be wrong.

Many thanks,

Comment: You may not have posted enough information to allow us to provide an answer.

Comment: Edit: never mind. @BlaiseDoughan knows all there is to know about JAXB and then some. 1+ to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to omit the XML declaration:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
```

I would create a StAX `XMLStreamWriter` to wrap your output and keep marshalling to that which will help manage your namespace declarations and add a root element.

Comment: The setProperty did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your second example it looks like you're trying to marshal several different objects in sequence to the same outputstream (or writer, or whatever).  Even if you can suppress the XML declarations this will not result in well-formed XML as the resulting file will have more than one root element, a better approach would be to aim for one `<FlightDetails>` containing several `<FlightDetailsCollection>` elements.  Exactly how you achieve that depends on the details of your JAXB classes.